# Custom toolbar button in tinymce in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tinymce

I need to insert a custom button in the tinymce toolbar in angular which passes me a parameter to a function, for example:

```
<button  mat-flat-button class="btn-primary" (click)="addVariable(i)">+ variabile</button>
```

where `i` is an index of a for within the html, so I have to pass it via the function call in the html, how can I put it here:

```
<editor apiKey="test" id="block{{i+1}}" [(ngModel)]="block.text" [init]="{
        height: 200,
        newline_behavior: 'linebreak',
        menubar: false,
        plugins: ['code'],
        toolbar: 'fontfamily | formatselect | bold italic fontsize forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code ',
        font_family_formats: 'Calibri=Calibri; Helvetica=Helvetica; Omnes=Omnes;',
        font_size_formats: '17pt 18pt 19pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 30pt',
}" ></editor>
```